# Line $L$ is tangent to the circle at $P$. Prove that no other point on $L$ can possibly intersect the circle.

Tags: geometry, logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 170)

> 8. In Figure 5.67, line $L$ is tangent to the circle at $P$. Prove that no other point on $L$ can possibly intersect the circle. [Hint: If $Q$ is a point on $L$ and $P\neq Q$, show that $d(O, Q) > d(O, P)$. Cf. Theorem 3-5.]

[image]

**Proof**:

Let:

- $C$ be a circle with radius $r$ and center $O$.
- $L$ a line tangent to $C$ at point $P$.

**Show**:

$$
\lnot \exists Q(Q \in L \land Q \neq P \land Q \in C)
$$

or, equivalently:

$$
\forall Q(Q \in L \to (Q \neq P \to Q \notin C))
$$

*I will use Fitch-style natural deduction system (indented bars denote sub-proofs). Added instantiated theorems and axioms to the premises*.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{1.\,P \in C\\
2.\,P \in L\\
3.\,P \in C \leftrightarrow d(O, P) = r\\
4.\,Q \in C \leftrightarrow d(O, Q) = r\\
5.\,d(O, Q)^2 = d(P, Q)^2 + d(O,P)^2 \qquad \text{Pythagoras}\\
6.\,0 = d(P, Q) \leftrightarrow Q = P \qquad \text{DIST 1}
}{
 \fitch{7.\,Q \in L}{
    \fitch{8.\,Q \neq P}{
      \fitch{9.\,Q \in C}{
       10.\,d(O, Q) = r \be{4,9}
       11.\,d(O, P) = r \be{3,1}
       12.\,d(O, Q) = d(O, P) \qe{11,10}
       13.\,d(O, Q)^2 = d(O, P)^2 \qquad \text{arithmetic}\\
       14.\,d(O, Q)^2 = d(P, Q)^2 + d(O,P)^2 \R{5}
       15.\,d(O, Q)^2 = d(P, Q)^2 + d(O,Q)^2 \qe{12,14}
       16.\,0 = d(P, Q)^2 \qquad \text{arithmetic}\\
       17.\,0 = d(P, Q) \qquad \text{arithmetic}\\
       18.\,Q = P \be{6,17}
       19.\,\bot \ii{8,18}
      }\\
      20.\,Q \notin C \ni{10-19}
    }\\
    21.\,Q \neq P \to Q \notin C \ii{8-20}
  }\\
  22.\,Q \in L \to (Q \neq P \to Q \notin C)\ii{7-21}
  23.\,\forall Z(Z \in L \to (Z \neq P \to Z \notin C)) \Ai{22}
}
$

Is this symbolization and proof correct ?

Comment: Any proof depends strongly on how *tangent* is defined. One my show -- using laws of symmetry -- the a circle an d a line have at most two points in common.  Then define a line to be tangent iff they share exactly one point.  Then one can show that the tangent is orthogonal the radius through the common point and the circle's center solely by using the definition of a circle.

Comment: Could you tell me how would you use the laws of symmetry to show that a circle and a line have at most two points in common, @Michael Hoppe ?

Comment: Of course.  We know: (1)  Only symmetric points determine a line segment which is orthogonally halved by the axis of symmetry.  (2) Only points of the axis have the same distance to symmetric points.  Now take two points on the circle.  From (1) and (2) we know that their axis of symmetry contains the center of the circle and is orthogonal to their line segment.  From here it's impossible that more than two points of the circle lie on the same straight line as there are different axis of symmetry for three points of a line.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael Hoppe.